# How to indent RSpec output JSON file

Tags: json, rspec

I'm running my RSpecs like this:

```
RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['spec', '-f', 'json', '--out', 'output.json'])
```

I'm getting the output in the `output.json` file, but the output is not indented properly. It's all in one line. Is there a way to indent the JSON output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSpec JSON formatter does not include spacing, because the JSON output is ordinarily used by another program, not a human.

If you need to view the JSON in the file, I suggest either a browser plugin, or an editor that can reformat the JSON for you.